# CRMFusion Dupeblocker issue with insufficient privileges

Tags: dupeblocker

I am struggling with this issue because the error message gives no clue as to what privileges are missing on what objects.  Any hints or tips as to how to find the gap?

Thank you.

Comment: More info please?  What is the user doing?  Where/when does the message occur?  Is it all users, or just specific ones?

Comment: Not enough information here, but I have seen insufficient privileges errors with DupeBlocker - which assumes that whoever is using it is a full System Administrator. Are you a full sysadmin?

Answer (score 0):

One approach to get to the bottom of this might be to setup a debug log on a user that can replicate the privileges error, have them (or you if can login as that user) execute the steps to create said error condition, and then review the log file. If memory serves me correct crmfusion generates sufficiently detailed logs so this should provide more detail on when the error is happening eg at record merge. From there you should be able to determine what user profile sobject permission is required to enable dedup process to complete without error. Usually a create or delete
perm on whatever you're deduping. Good luck.